# Does JS (chrome) string interning on object/maps merging?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, memory-management

Given we have 2 objects as follows:

```
let obj1 = {
  "ac": 1,
  "com.ac": 1,
  "edu.ac": 1,
  "gov.ac": 1,
  "net.ac": 1,
  "mil.ac": 1,
  "org.ac": 1
...
}

let obj2 = {
  "accident-investigation.aero": 1,
  "accident-prevention.aero": 1,
  "aerobatic.aero": 1,
  "aeroclub.aero": 1,
  "aerodrome.aero": 1,
...
}

let obj3 = {...obj1, ...obj2};
```

At some point we need to check whether we have an entry for some key looking into both objects, so we merge them into `obj3` to have only 1 call (`let value = obj3["someKey"]`).

The objects contains thousands of properties and the major part of the consumed memory is taken by keys as strings so i care about the memory consumption.

Will `obj3` reuse `obj1` and `obj2` keys strings (string interning) or the memory consumption will be near equal to obj1 and obj2 together?

Compared to the following alternative implementation with every entry marked with `boolean` whether it belongs to obj1 or obj2:

```
let obj4 = {
  "ac": {
    offset: 1,
    fromObj1: true
  },
  "accident-investigation.aero": {
    offset: 1,
    fromObj1: false
  },
...
}
```

what's more optimal from memory consumption: `obj1 + obj2 + obj3` vs. `obj4`?

Comment: You could just try both approaches and look at the Memory profiler tab of the Chrome dev tools...

Comment: is it possible to measure object memory size there?

Comment: That's kind of the point of it, yes.